# window.setInterval in Javascript do not run a function more than once

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, timer

I want to update a partial view every 5000 ms (for example).

I used bellow code to do it:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    $.get("/Features/ShowDateTime").then(function (r) {
        $('#divDateTime').html(r);
    });
}, 5000)
```

This function run every 5000 ms truly (examined by using `debugger` command in the inner function) but `ShowDateTime` action run once (examined by using break-point in the action in its controller).

So, what is the problem?

Comment: Your code looks fine. It should keep hitting that endpoint in every 5 seconds

Comment: I also suggest moving out the `$('#divDateTime')` selector outside and store it in a variable and use that variable inside your setInterval snippet

Comment: Might be a cache issue ... try `$.get("/Features/ShowDateTime?_"+Date.now())` and see if anything changes

Comment: Are you testing in IE ? Can you try in chrome ?

Comment: Hey @Shyju . This has nothing to do with `$('#divDateTime')`. Before it, action must run. In chrome that works truly!

Comment: Hey @charlietfl . That works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the code itself is working, it is likely you are getting cached data back on subsequent calls. You need to cache-bust your calls. An easy way is to simply append the current timestamp to the end of the URL:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    $.get("/Features/ShowDateTime?" + Date.now()).then(function (r) {
        $('#divDateTime').html(r);
    });
}, 5000)
```

This will cause your browser to think it is a different URL each time so it won't cache and return the same result.

Comment: Why not just use `.ajax()` and set `cache: false`, I think it is easier to read and shows intent to another programmer.  Appending dates to the end of the url seems like a pretty hacky way to do it.

Comment: @RyanWilson that's what happens also when you set `cache:false`...a timestamp based value is added to url

Comment: Yeah, fixed the syntax error. The `?` needs to be in the quotation marks. You can also use `ajax()` with `cache:false`, but the cache-busting method I mentioned is universal regardless of which AJAX library/method you use, so I like to promote it over library-specific configurations. @RyanWilson

Comment: @samanime I see why you go with that. Seeing as it is universal, I can see it's value.